# How to get maximum document scrolltop value

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I am making some plugin and I need to get maximum `scrollTop` value of the document.
Maximum `scrollTop` value is `2001` , but `$(document).height()` returns `2668` and `$('body')[0].scrollHeight` gives me `undefined`.

How to get `2001` through javascript/jquery?!

Comment: I think i just figured out... $(document).height - $(window).height

Comment: No... that gives me 2011. Help please!

Comment: Did you try `$(document).prop("scrollHeight");`, or if you have margins messing things up : `$(document).outerHeight() - $(window).outerHeight()`, or to get the total scrollheight minus the window height : `$(document).prop("scrollHeight")-$(window).outerHeight()`.

Comment: Nah... first one gives me 2011 , and the second one NaN ...

Comment: `outerHeight(true)` ?

Comment: For a div scroll, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17244962

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The code in your comments should work:

```
$(document).height() - $(window).height()
```

Here's an example that alerts when you scroll to the maximum scroll position: http://jsfiddle.net/DWn7Z/

Comment: Ugh... why do I have those additional 10 pixels? :(

Comment: @hjuster Try `outerHeight` for both?

Comment: again 2011 with outerHeight, no changes... But the difference is always 10px, no matter the resolution, which are actually great news!

Comment: How do you know that it should be 2001? Does my example work correctly for you?

Comment: @hjuster could be the scrollbar height

Comment: This is **incorrect** because it doen't consider the horizontal scroll bar height. The window height includes the scroll bar height while the document height doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer i wrote https://stackoverflow.com/a/48246003/7668448, it's about a polyfill for scrollTopMax which is a native property for Element objects. (only mozilla). Look at the response, you can really like it.

Bellow just a quick snippet. The answer in the link is more rich (make sure to look).

```
(function(elmProto){
    if ('scrollTopMax' in elmProto) {
        return;
    }
    Object.defineProperties(elmProto, {
        'scrollTopMax': {
            get: function scrollTopMax() {
              return this.scrollHeight - this.clientTop;
            }
        },
        'scrollLeftMax': {
            get: function scrollLeftMax() {
              return this.scrollWidth - this.clientLeft;
            }
        }
    });
}
)(Element.prototype);
```

use example:

```
var el = document.getElementById('el1');
var max = el.scrollLeftMax;
```

Comment: I believe `this.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight` is what would be equivalent to `this.scrollTopMax`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "guess" the maximum scrolltop value, maybe you should compare the height of the document and the viewport height (size of your window).

```
/**
 * Return a viewport object (width and height)
 */
function viewport()
{
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window))
    {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] }
}

// Retrieve the height of the document, including padding, margin and border
var documentHeight = $(document).outerheight(true);
var viewPortData = viewport();

var maxScrollTop = documentHeight - viewPortData.height;
```

Of course, in your plugin, you should also add a listener on the resize event, and re-calculate the maximum scrollTop.

Comment: with outerHeight on window and document, it is working, as with my function. Try it ! http://fiddle.jshell.net/9MAVM/3/

Comment: For me its not working, i have always those paranormal additional 10px. Your function gives me the same result as the one from my first comment ,,$(document).height - $(window).height " . But anyway, thanks , consider this solved...

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla Javascript I'm currently doing this:

```
getScrollTopMax = function () {
  var ref;
  return (ref = document.scrollingElement.scrollTopMax) != null
      ? ref
      : (document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
};
```

This returns [Gecko's non-standard scrollTopMax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTopMax) if it exists, otherwise calculates it. I'm using `document.scrollingElement` here, which only exists on particular browsers, but it's [easy to polyfill](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/document.scrollingElement).

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me, for scrolling of the main document as requested by OP:

```
window.document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.document.documentElement.clientHeight
```

Comment: I had to add this answer because all previous answers either did not work for me or were not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, a simple and easy solution :-

`document.body.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;`

Found this on W3 Schools....