# Finding the maximum bottom value of scrollTop on a div?

Tags: jquery

I need a way to automatically find the maximum bottom value of scrollTop, of the div id "#box".

Something like this: [How to get maximum document scrolltop value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965296/how-to-get-maximum-document-scrolltop-value)

but just in a div, not the whole browser window.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

here you go:

```
var trueDivHeight = $('.someclass')[0].scrollHeight;
var divHeight = $('.someclass').height();
var scrollLeft = trueDivHeight - divHeight;
alert(scrollLeft);
```

Simplified

Answer (score 18):

Here's a version that accounts for padding and uses `prop` instead of accessing the DOM element directly.

```
$('#box').prop('scrollHeight') - $('#box').innerHeight();
```

Answer (score 4):

In vanilla JS:

```
var maxScrollTop = el.scrollHeight - el.offsetHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

look here a complete answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48246003/7668448

**What about using that with jquery:**

```
var max = $('#element')[0].scrollLeftMax; // when using the polyfill
var max =  $('#element')[0].scrollLeftMaxi(); // when using the other alternative more support IE6+
```