# Why can't move the image with ++imgbox.scrollLeft?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to move a serie of images from right to left using javascript.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    function move(){
        var speed = 500;
        var imgbox = document.getElementById("imgbox");
        imgbox.innerHTML += imgbox.innerHTML;
        var span = imgbox.getElementsByTagName("span");
        var timer = window.setInterval(marquee,speed);

        function marquee(){
            console.log(imgbox.scrollLeft);
            console.log(span[0].offsetWidth);
            if( imgbox.scrollLeft > span[0].offsetWidth){
                imgbox.scrollLeft = 0;
            }else{
                ++imgbox.scrollLeft;
                console.log("in else block");
                console.log(imgbox.scrollLeft);
                }
        }
    }
    move();
}
```

```css
div{
    width: 933px;
    height: 129px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
 <div id="imgbox">
    <span>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7J9w.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh7YJ.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uIog.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5GCW.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

When to open it with firefox, js run in `else block` ,why `imgbox.scrollLeft` can't increase?`imgbox.scrollLeft` keep value as `0` ,not increased as `1`,`2`,`3`.......
How to fix my js or css ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the style helps. With `white-space` option allowing text wrapping, there is no horizontal overflow, the element needs no horizintal scrolling, and `.scrollLeft` is automatically reset to 0. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft, section *Setting the value*.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    function move(){
        var speed = 50; // I made it faster.
        var imgbox = document.getElementById("imgbox");
        imgbox.innerHTML += imgbox.innerHTML;
        var span = imgbox.getElementsByTagName("span");
        var timer = window.setInterval(marquee,speed);

        function marquee(){
            console.log(imgbox.scrollLeft);
            console.log(span[0].offsetWidth);
            //                                    see UPD -v
            if( imgbox.scrollLeft > span[0].offsetWidth || imgbox.scrollLeft >= imgbox.scrollWidth - imgbox.clientWidth ){
                imgbox.scrollLeft = 0;
            }else{
                ++imgbox.scrollLeft;
                console.log("in else block");
                console.log(imgbox.scrollLeft);
                }
        }
    }
    move();
}
```

```css
div{
    width: 933px;
    height: 129px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; /* <-- */
}
```

```html
<div id="imgbox">
    <span>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7J9w.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh7YJ.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uIog.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5GCW.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

**UPD** per @Jaromanda_X. There is a another problem with the author's code: the scrolling stops when `imgbox.scrollLeft` reaches 910, for

> If specified as a value greater than the maximum that the content can be scrolled, scrollLeft is set to the maximum.

The maximum value of `.scrollLeft` is defined as `.scrollWidth - .clientWidth` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5704386/6632736). So, the condition for resetting `.scrollLeft` ought to be `imgbox.scrollLeft > span[0].offsetWidth || imgbox.scrollLeft >= imgbox.scrollWidth - imgbox.clientWidth`. Perhaps, it can be simplified.

Comment: Yes, I have. This is a different issue with the code, which the author didn't ask to resolve.